# How to add a space between items in a string

Tags: java, string

How can I add a space between distinct items in a string . 
Given the string for example :

`"22@((12@45)&14)"`

How can I make it a string separated by spaces like this :

`"22 @ ( ( 12 @ 45 ) & 14 )"`

Note that numbers greater than 9 don't have a space in between their digits

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. if you could share what you have tried, that would be splendid. really. please take a look to [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and see what you can improve on the question. happy coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have only integer numbers, it can be implemented as following:

```
        private static String formatExpression(String input) {
            return String.join(" ", input.split("((?<=\\D)|(?=\\D))"));
        }
```

1. Splitting by non-digits using lookahead/lookbehind syntax;
2. Rejoining to String using space delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this, it works, and it will give you a base for modifications if you need them:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String someString = "22@((12@45)&14)";
    int length = someString.length();
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        char c = someString.charAt(i);
        result.append(c);
        if (!Character.isDigit(c) || (i < length-1 && !Character.isDigit(someString.charAt(i+1)))){
            result.append(" ");
        }
    }
    System.out.println(result.toString());
}
```